# Use of Accept-charset HTTP header

Tags: http, rest, http-headers, rfc2616

What are the differences and advantages of using one over the other:

```
Accept: application/json;charset=utf-8
```

versus:

```
Accept: application/json
Accept-Charset: utf-8
```

Is the first form compliant to rfc 2616?

Note: could be json or xml, etc.

Comment: Not a definite answer, but check [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055849/accept-and-accept-charset-which-is-superior) for some comments

Comment: It is for "Server" to consider charset in Accept or not. But all the agents do work on Accept-charset


https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Content_negotiation

Answer (score 3):

Both of them are compliant. But I prefer second one.

"charset" parameter is for media type and media types are defined by [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types), not by RFC 2616.

- Even if the server understands RFC 2616, you cannot be sure it understands "charset" parameter.
- Some media types may not have "charset" parameter.

Comment: If a media type doesn't have a charset parameter then *both* forms are meaningless.

Comment: @JulianReschke Why an Accept-Charset form is also meaningless if a media type doesn't have a "charset" parameter? RFC 2616 and draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-24 doesn't say that a charset in an Accept-Charset header is equivalent to a "charset" parameter for a media type.

Comment: do you have an example of a media type that supports different charsets but does not have a charset param?

Comment: @JulianReschke [application/ld+json](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/ld+json) does not have a charset parameter and RFC 6839 says "Per [RFC4627], JSON is allowed to be represented using UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32."