# Response Headers

Tags: httpresponse

"Name two headers that, if present n an http response, always have to be processed in a particular order. state the order and explain."

I have researched this online and in my textbook: Web Application Architecture by Shklar and Rosen.

My initial thought was that it was "www authentication" and "location"  however with other  research i have become more confused.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP headers are independant of each other.  They can appear in any order, and be processed in any order.  I have never seen multiple HTTP headers that were meant to work together, let alone require being processed in a particular order.

The `WWW-Authentication` and `Location` headers have nothing to do with each other.  `WWW-Authentication` is used to request/negotiate auth credentials for a single URL.  `Location` is used during redirect responses (3xx other than 304) to specify a different URL to send a request to.

There was a [recent discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055849/accept-and-accept-charset-which-is-superior) about the processing semantics of the `Accept` and `Accept-Charset` headers, but that relationship is not officially defined, and it applies to request headers, not response headers.